# Error loading audio in LibGDX using MOE

Tags: ios, libgdx, intel, robovm

I used to load audio files without problems in RoboVM, but now that I'm using Multi-OS Engine to run libGDX game in iOS.

This is my code to load audio files:

```
Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sounds/pop.mp3"));
```

And this is what I see in console:

> 2017-04-07 17:27:13.871271-0500 FacesChess[2258:359966] OAL Error:
>   -[OALAudioFile initWithUrl:reduceToMono:]: Could not open url file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/344E150B-DDCA-45A7-B9A1-3EA14C60ECE6/FacesChess.app/assets/sounds/pop.mp3
>   (error code 0x7768743f: Unknown ext audio error) 2017-04-07
>   17:27:13.871403-0500 FacesChess[2258:359966] OAL Error:
>   -[OALSimpleAudio internalPreloadEffect:reduceToMono:]: Could not load effect
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/344E150B-DDCA-45A7-B9A1-3EA14C60ECE6/FacesChess.app/assets/sounds/pop.mp3

Moe plugin version: 1.3.3
LibGDX version = 1.9.6

I placed my mp3 files at assets folder in android module. I'm having the problem just with audio files, images are also in the same folder and there's not problem.

I read in other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802986/libgdx-ios-robovm-no-sound-unknown-ext-audio) this: "In my iOS project the only place iOS picks up the sounds is in the directory /data/sounds". But I haven't discover how to load files from data folder. I don't understand how do iOS file system works, documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling#platform-filesystems).

Comment: perhaps this can help you? http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=25733#p101561

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that iOS audio framework cannot load assets from the application.jar that MOE generates. Therefore, the audio resources have to be manually added to the Xcode project.

To do so, drag assets folder from android/assets into Xcode, making sure to select "Create Folder References".

[image: Make sure to select "Create Folder References"]

The folder has to be named assets because LibGDX uses a hardcoded path. Folder should shows up in blue in Xcode, otherwise the hierarchy will not be bundled correctly.

[image: This is how folder hierarchy should look like]

Thanks to sAm_vdP for the answer in badlogicgames.com [forum](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=25733#p101561).